# Non english text in IE8 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to pass a string in my language (hebrew) to a script. 
I have built [this](http://s-maof.com/shorts/shorts_table.php) page

which contains an input text

```
<input type="text" class="filter"  id="Filter"/>
```

and a script to get the text when changes and then the table filters out the results

```
    <script> 
    $('#Filter').change(function() {
    var str = $('#Filter').val();
    str = str.replace(/[\s]/g, '_'); //replcae spaces to "_" (Otherwise we get errors) 
   $('#Table').load('printShorts.server.php?Sortby=<?echo $sort;?>&dir=<?echo    $direction;?>&filter='+str+'&no-cache=' + (new Date()).getTime() ).fadeIn("slow");

});
</script>
```

Which passes the values great - in FF and chrome. 
The problem starts with IE8 (and probably 9)
what do you guys suggest I'll do? 
I don't even know if there is a debugging sofware for IE like firebug..

also if you noticed in the page, I used UTF8 like so

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

1. another question - I don't know why the up and down arrow gets rendered with blue border only in IE!! what is up with that?

help will be appriciated..

Comment: in IE you can see the error at bottom left corner .copy that error . press F12 in IE there is developer tool available in IE 8 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what little information you've given of the actual error I'm going to guess at the problem. You are not URL encoding the str parameter and being utf-8 there might be plea to of characters that are invalid in a URL. Chrome and FF handles some of those gracefully it might be that IE8 does not (previous versions didn't)

Instead of `+str+` then use `+encodeURIComponent(str)+`

That will encode what ever is in str and ensure that the resulting URL is valid

Comment: thanks alot - saved me a lot of time! btw - need a php equivalent to the encodeURIComponent - and I found urlencode to work fine! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you have to save file in certain UTF-8 format, you can setup it in your text/code editor.